# window.location.href redirect throws history.pushState() errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a set up where based on the URL I am loading a different React application bundle. On initial login and selection of a particular subroute, I am trying to push the user to the second application using

`window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/' + appName + '/' + 'dashboard';`

Even though I am using react-router's `<BrowserRouter>`, I have to do this to remove the initial bundle and load the next one. However, I am now running into this issue that I cannot seem to figure out.

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://dashboard/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:3000' and URL 'http://localhost:3000/scoop/dashboard'.
```

Not sure exactly what I am doing wrong and why `history.pushState` is being called at all.

Comment: *"...and why history.pushState is being called at all...."* Presumably because react-router has an event handler hooked up (perhaps to the `unload` event).

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.props.history.push(`/${appName}/${dashboard}`);
```

try this one, this should work